# Scrum Sprint pre-story research

Tags: scrum, estimation

When and who undertakes the work to sufficiently gather answers so that we can start to write stories for an upcoming sprint.  Is this work done continuously and in parallel to existing sprints by the product owner?  I guess this then creates tasks for a sprint such as investigate x and y.  What if the PO suddenly requires a developer to answer some of the questions by trying stuff out?  I understand the idea of spiking and creating r & d tasks.  I guess I want to avoid the main dev of a feature being delayed to a following sprint too often.

Comment: Better suited at programmers....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 1):

The team determines how much new story work it can do during a sprint.  The amount of time they have to do that work is some percentage of the work day.  Depending on the responsibilities of team members (customer support, bug fixes, emails, PTO, other duties) that amount varies from team to team.  I like to see 10-15% of the work day dedicated to "planning" for the next sprint.  That includes helping the PO research, writing stories, breaking up stories, design sessions, what-if scenarios, etc.  I think the key is not to shoe-horn every one of these types of tasks into a sprint but rather to set the correct time allocation to doing the sprint work.  Maybe something like 30 hours/wk is an average number.

So to directly answer your question; the planning work is done in parallel to the current sprint work.

Answer (score 0):

We usually have one or two meetings to talk about future stories. Also, we reserve some overhead time in each sprint to check out things we need to know to start a story. The meetings help determining which stories will probably shop up in the next sprint, so we know which questions to get answers to during the reserved time in the current sprint.

Answer (score 0):

For us, if it's a large project, we will have kickoff meetings to brainstorm the project.  There is often a knowledge gap for PO's between what they want to do and what they don't know we can do that these meetings can fill.

When new stories are created, we try to assign story points to them at some point before the next planning meeting so the PO has time to prioritize the list before that meeting.

I'm not sure of the kind of situation you describe where a PO would "suddenly" need a dev to try stuff out.  In that case, I would offer a spike in the next sprint.  Generally using new technologies isn't something that happens every sprint so this should suffice.  If not, perhaps the sprints are a bit too long for this purpose (a trade off to be considered at least)  Another alternative would be to introduce an evergreen story for trying stuff out.  I've seen teams have these kinds of stories for tech debt payback - you could off an either/or situation.  Sometimes dev fixes tech debt, sometimes they try stuff out.  And if you run out of tech debt somehow, you can always grab another regular story to put in its place.

Answer (score 0):

We typically reserve a sprint or two after a big release for research and proof of concept stories. Doing research as part of the regular sprint seems like it would be problematic. You'd probably use that time to absorb mis-estimations for value-adding stories and end up never using it for actual research.

If a new story drops into the backlog that needs research and the PO runs it up to the top of your backlog then the team should include some research time into their actual estimate. I would only do that if I didn't have the luxury of a research/prototyping sprint ahead of time though since estimating research can be a bit nebulous.

Answer (score 0):

Who: Product owner. Stories and Product backlog are his responsibilities. Product owners are generally experienced people; even if they are not technical they can certainly perceive implementation complexities at abstract level. Still, if a story has gray area PO must ask right people the right question. He can ask developers, testers, peers, clients and even scrum masters.

When: all the time.. Continuously. PO must not do anything but (1) provide (or get) answers for the team’s questions regarding scope and function, (2) and gather data that would refine the stories and their scope: thus proactively solving the queries of his team.

Bottom line is if product owner is not giving good stories to the team then he is not doing his job. Stories can be written by anyone but in the end it’s PO who ensure that Product Backlog is in order and that top priority stories are defined.